# maximum product of sum of array elements in two group

Tags: algorithm, math

if we have a array. what can be the logic to divide the array into two groups such that the product of sum of elements of group 1 and sum of elements of group 2 can be maximum.

```
Ex1-> arr[] = {9,16,5}
     Here we can have 2 groups with maximum product of sum as {16} and {5,9}
     Ans-> 16*(5+9) = 16*14 = 224

Ex2-> arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
      2 groups which can be formed which can give maximum product of sum is {1,2,5} and {3,4}
      Ans-> 8*7 = 56
```

Comment: Same as minimal difference between sums of subsets? See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/

Comment: yes, you are right. It is minimal difference between sums of subsets. Thanks for help.